# Accessing localStorage to set theme in Nuxt.js SSR before page render

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, vue-meta

I'm trying to set the theme of a webpage for unregistered users based off of their preference, stored in `localStorage`. However, there is a small flicker from the default theme to their preferred theme when doing so in the default layout of a Nuxt.js SSR app. To prevent this I'd need to block the page from rendering before the data is pulled from `localStorage`, but I can't seem to figure out how to do so in Nuxt.

```
<template>
  <div :data-theme="theme" class="flex min-h-screen flex-col justify-between">
    <TheHeader :currentTheme="theme" @themeChange="setTheme" />
    <Nuxt />
    <TheFooter />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      theme: "light",
    };
  },
  head() {
    return {
      htmlAttrs: {
        "data-theme": this.theme,
      },
    };
  },
  beforeMount() {
    // NOTE: first check if registered user, and perhaps store in Vuex Store
    // TODO: no flicker
    if (localStorage.theme === "dark") {
      this.theme = "dark";
    } else {
      this.theme = "light";
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setTheme(theme) {
      this.theme = theme;
      localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
    },
  },
  created() {
    // for emitted event to be called in the layout
    this.$nuxt.$on("changeTheme", (theme) => {
      this.setTheme(theme);
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

I'm using [daisyUI TailwindCSS](https://daisyui.com/), which relies on setting the `data-theme` of the main `<html>` tag to one of its options.

---

#### What I've tried

1. Creating a Nuxt plugin, as plugins run before page render. This hasn't worked out, as I need to update a data value in the default layout page.
2. Running initial theme change in `created()` - `localStorage` is outside the scope.
3. Dynamically setting the htmlAttr (`"data-theme": localStorage.theme ? localStorage.theme : "light"`) - also failed because localStorage can't be accessed here.

So is there a way to accomplish this pre-render theme setting to prevent flickering?

Comment: You should probably use a cookie here since it's available in the server side.